# Derivatives of $e^x$

Tags: derivatives

The question I am trying to find is this: Find all points on the curve $y=xe^x$ where the gradient of the tangent is $2e$. This has to do with derivatives. I am not understanding what to do after I try to make it equal to $x$

Comment: When you say gradient of the tangent, do you mean the slope of the tangent line at a point?  Since a gradient is a type of derivative, someone reading this might think that you're talking about the second derivative?

Comment: Why did you make the derivative equal to $x$?

Comment: $y'=xe^x+e^x$ and if $(x+1)e^x=2e$ then x=1$

Comment: I was trying to find a point, so I thought that I would need to find x so I made it x equal to the rest of the equation

Comment: Yes, and janmarqz showed how x= 1 for that condition.  Since y= xe^x, y will be equal to 1(e^1)= e.  The point you are trying to find is (1, e).